# Snort DNS rule immersive labs

Tags: dns, snort

The question is

> "Create a rule to detect DNS requests to 'interbanx', then test the
> rule with the scanner and submit the token."

My rule is:

```
alert udp any any -> any 53 (msg:"alert"; sid:5000001; content:"|09|interbanx|00|";)
```

It says no packets were found on pcap (this question in immersive labs).

What am I missing?

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* - A description of your setup and how you are testing. It is not clear from your description that this rule gets even loaded, that snort will even see the packets and that the packets actually contain the content you are looking for. First make sure that all of these is actually true before looking for a problem with the rule itself.